# How to align a HTML definition list (<dl>) horizontally without limiting term or definition in height?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to align a HTML defintion list horizontally, so the term is on the left, and the definition is on the right.

Both term and definition can be very long, so they can be wider than the available width and will wrap.

With my CSS, I have no problem with definitions that wrap and so are higher than the corresponding term. But in the rare case when the term wraps and is higher than the corresponding definition, I don't get the following definition to clear properly.

You can see this in my jsFiddle, where the definition "555" does not properly align with the term "555".

http://jsfiddle.net/jmuheim/kjf8f/

Any help on how to fix this is really appreciated. Requirements:

- I want the definition to use all available horizontal space on the right, so I don't want to use a fixed width for the `<dd>` tag.
- I don't want the definition in any situation to be positioned under the corresponding term.

Comment: Since you really want to display a table of definitions in a tabular manner, changing `dl` to `table` markup is the best option, if you have control over the markup. Unfortunately, there is apparently no way to style a `dl` as a table in CSS, due to its lack of internal structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might do the trick.  Add the following CSS rule:

```
dd:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

The pseudo-element will clear the floated `<dd>` element and this will ensure that the next `<dt>` starts on a new line.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/TXYGk/

Comment: This is about perfect, thank you! I just had to also remove the margins from the dt. Now it is 100% the way I wanted it to be. http://jsfiddle.net/jmuheim/TXYGk/2/

Answer (score 2):

I really like Marc's answer. Another solution, if it doesn't wreck your design requirements, is probably to float the DDs as well, and give both the DDs and DTs (and horizontal margins) percentage based widths instead of fixed-pixel widths: http://jsfiddle.net/dHRSz/1/

Or consider that, depending on the content, a table (with the terms wrapped in `<th scope="row">`) might not be too inappropriate to mark this up.

Edit - copied CSS from jsfiddle:

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.block {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

dl {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

dt {
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 28%;
}

dd {
    float: left;
    width: 71%;
    margin: 0 0 4px 1%;
}
```

Comment: I knew about the possibility to use percentages, but often they are not what my requirements say. And yeah, a table with 1:1 relation between title and content fields is okay, but I guess a definition list is more appropriate to use. Thanks anyway!