# How can I switch between <dt> and <dd> alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment

In a form on my site the `<dt>` are the labels and the `<dd>` are the textboxes.
I want the `<dt>` to float right from the text boxes (the `<dd>`).

I've tried using `align="right"` on the `<dt>`, with no luck
and also tried to use style... but I wasn't sure what to write there...

Thanks  :)

Answer (score 0):

You really ought to search SO before you post. Here's a recent post on DL styling that is likely to be helpful. [How to align a HTML definition list (<dl>) horizontally without limiting term or definition in height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138433/how-to-align-a-html-definition-list-dl-horizontally-without-limiting-term-or/19138866#19138866)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did searched for a solution before I posted. The strange thing is that when I copy my form and css code to JSFiddle I get it just right. Exactly the way I want it to be. But when I use the same code on my side the <dt> tag just doesn't move. It's like it stuck on the left.   I noticed that if I write a simple form with dt and dd tags on JSFiddle it automatically will align to the right. What sould I do?

Comment: I managed to get the <dt> tag to appear on the right side of the <dd> with <dt style="float:right;">, But for some reason the form is not starting from the right side of the page, It got closer to the middle. How can I get it to stick to the right?

Comment: Sorry, there's no good way to answer this without seeing the specific page. All I can recommend is to inspect the page in the developer tools and learn how to use the styles and metrics tools to understand exactly why things are laying out where they are.